# Form Data not properly posting

Tags: javascript, axios

```
let formdata = new FormData();
    const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("UserAuth")).token;
    formdata.append('model', model)
    formdata.append('make', make)
    formdata.append('vin', vin)
    formdata.append('year', year)
    formdata.append('askingprice', askPrice)
    formdata.append('customer', _id);
    formdata.append('mileage', mileage)
    formdata.append('bodytype', bodyType)
    formdata.append('condition', condition)
    formdata.append('image', pictures)

    let data = new FormData()
    let headers = {
        // withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    }

    axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/tradein/create/5e838c95f2064847a843a114', data, headers)
    .then((res) => {
       console.log(res)
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

So i'm trying to add the the form data object to the backend rest api, but I get an error code 400. I believe my form is not correctly submitting, but I do not see why. When I logged the values into my console, they were correctly named and assigned. For reference, here is where my request is being sent to:

```
exports.create = (req,res) =>
{
    let form = new formidable.IncomingForm()
    form.keepExtensions = true
    form.parse(req,(err,fields,files)=>{

        if(err)
        {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: 'Trade-in car couldnt be uploaded'
            })
        }
// check for all the required fiels of vehilce and send error msg
const{make,model,year,mileage,bodytype,askingprice} = fields
if(!make || !model|| !mileage|| !year||  !askingprice||  !bodytype)
    {
        return res.status(400).json({
            error: 'all required attributes for tradein-vehicle are needed'
        }) 
    }
// get the data from the client or apia
        let tradein = new TradeIn(fields)
// load the image 
        if(files.image){
// verify if image is too large
            if(files.image.size > 1000000)
            {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error: 'file size is too large,has to be less than 1mb'
                })
            }
            tradein.image.data = fs.readFileSync(files.image.path)
            tradein.image.contentType = files.image.type

        }

        tradein.save((err,result) =>{
            if(err){
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error: err
                })
            }
            //send the form data back to db
            res.json(result);
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: so are you getting any of the several error messages defined in the server code back with your 400 page?

Comment: @BenMcIntyre So I looked at the error.response in my axios catch and I get the 400 that pertains to 'all required attributes for tradin-vehicle are needed', yet I have defined them above and are actively being set when I run the function. I'm thinking that I am not properly sending the FormData properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are posting an empty FormData object here :

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/tradein/create/5e838c95f2064847a843a114', data, headers)
```

I think you want to post the `formdata` instance instead of `data` –